# Listar conjunto de dados contidos em Pacotes no R

Tags: r, packages

Gostaria de saber como ver todos os dados contidos em pacotes no R.

**POR EXEMPLO:** O pacote MASS possui os dados de carros de 1993 (Cars93) mas eu gostaria de saber se tem como ver outros dados contidos nesse pacote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem sim, rode o comando abaixo:

```
data(package = "MASS")
```

Comment: **Obrigado Vinícius.**